# How to implement maximum likelihood (ML) detector in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, digital-communications, signal-detection, estimation, mimo

Consider the MIMO system which has $N_t$ antennas at transmitter and $N_r$ antennas at receiver and uses Generalized space shift keying (GSSK) modulation. The received signal is given by:

$$Y = H X + N_w\tag 1$$

where, $H$ is the channel of dimension $N_r \times N_t$, $N_w$ is AWGN of dimension $N_r \times L$, $X = [\mathbf{x_1},\mathbf{x_2},...,\mathbf{x_L}]$ is transmitted signal sequence of dimension $N_t \times L$ and $L$ denotes total time slots.

Each transmitted signal is drawn from the transmit symbol set $\mathbb{X}_{\text{GSSK}}=\{\mathbf{x[1],\mathbf{x}[2],...,\mathbf{x}[N]}\}$, where $\mathbf{x}[n]$ is $n^{\text{th}}$ GSSK modulated symbol of dimension $N_t \times 1$ and $\mathbf{x}[n] \in \mathbb{X}_{\text{GSSK}}$.

Then according to the paper titled "Supervised Learning-Based Semi-Blind Detection
for Generalized Space Shift Keying MIMO Systems", it is found that the Maximum Likelihood detection for the system in equation (1) is given as:

$$(\hat{H}, \hat{X}) = \underset{H \in \mathbb{C}^{N_r \times N_t}\\X \in \mathbb{X}_{\text{GSSK}}^L}{\arg\,\min}\, \| Y- HX\|_{\text{F}}^2 \tag2 $$

such that $\mathbb{X}_{\text{GSSK}}^L$ is $L$ dimensional $\mathbb{X}_{\text{GSSK}}$ and $|\mathbb{X}_{\text{GSSK}}^L| = N^L$,
where $|\cdot|$ denotes the cardinality of set, $\|\cdot\|_{\text{F}}$ denotes Frobenius norm.

My query I had implemented eq (2) in MATLAB but not getting it correctly.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Matlab code:

```
% For ML detector
% This is only for Nt = 8 antennas

clc;
clear all;
close all;

%% Initializations
iter = 10^3; % iterations , assumed by me
L = 500; % length of transmitted sig or total number of time slots
N_t = 8; % number of antennas at tag
N_r = 2; % number of antennas at reader
N_s = 1; % number of antennas at source
n_t = 2;
M_1 = nchoosek(N_t,n_t); 
M = floor(log2(M_1));
N = 2^M; % number of transmitted symbols
Labels = N; % number of labels are N starting from 1 to N
v_H = 1; % variance of channel, given in paper
No = 1;  % variance of AWGN, assumed
v_S = 1; % variance of source signal, assumed
al = 0.5; % backscatter coefficient
% We assume that the experiment is performed "iter" times for each SNR and
% in each "iter", there are total "L" sequence

    toterr_cnt_ML = [];
for snr = 0:3:21 % SNR in dB as per fig 3
    snr
    
    err_cnt_ML = 0;
    for it = 1:iter
        error_ML = 0;  x_4nrm = []; X = []; Wn = []; Y = []; AA_nrm = [];
        xs = sqrt(v_S/2)*(randn(1,1)+1i*randn(1,1)); % Complex Gaussian
        Htr = sqrt(v_H/2)*(randn(N_r,N_t)+1i*randn(N_r,N_t)); % Complex Gaussian
        Hst = sqrt(v_H/2)*(randn(N_t,N_s)+1i*randn(N_t,N_s)); % Complex Gaussian
    for sl = 1:L % for loop of slots
        sl
        %% Transmitted signal from tag (backscatterd sig)
        % 16 different backscattered symbols 
        x_1 = al*Hst.*[xs xs 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]'; x_2 = al*Hst.*[xs 0 xs 0 0 0 0 0 ]'; x_3 = al*Hst.*[xs 0 0 xs 0 0 0 0 ]'; x_4 = al*Hst.*[xs 0 0 0 xs 0 0 0 ]';
        x_5 = al*Hst.*[xs 0 0 0 0 xs 0 0 ]'; x_6 = al*Hst.*[xs 0 0 0 0 0 xs 0 ]'; x_7 = al*Hst.*[xs 0 0 0 0 0 0 xs ]'; x_8 = al*Hst.*[0 xs xs 0 0 0 0 0 ]';
        x_9 = al*Hst.*[0 xs 0 xs 0 0 0 0 ]'; x_10 = al*Hst.*[0 xs 0 0 xs 0 0 0 ]'; x_11 = al*Hst.*[0 xs 0 0 0 xs 0 0 ]'; x_12 = al*Hst.*[0 xs 0 0 0 0 xs 0 ]';
        x_13 = al*Hst.*[0 xs 0 0 0 0 0 xs]'; x_14 = al*Hst.*[0 0 xs xs 0 0 0 0]'; x_15 = al*Hst.*[0 0 xs 0 xs 0 0 0]'; x_16 = al*Hst.*[0 0 xs 0 0 xs 0 0]';
        [x, X_GSSK] = trans_signal(N,L,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7,x_8,x_9,x_10,x_11,x_12,x_13,x_14,x_15,x_16); % This is transmitted signal from tag 
        X = [X, x];
              
        %% AWGN
        AWGN = sqrt(No/2)*(randn(N_r,1)+1i*randn(N_r,1)); % Complex Gaussian
        Wn = [Wn, AWGN];
        %% Received Signal
        y_r_1 = (Htr*x);
        y_r = y_r_1+(10^(-snr/20).*AWGN); % Received Signal with other way 
        Y = [Y, y_r];
        %% Norm calculation
        A_nrm = frob_nrm_20oct23(y_r,Htr, x);
        AA_nrm = [AA_nrm, A_nrm];
        x_4nrm = [x_4nrm,x];
        
    end
        % x_hat calculation    
        [min_nrm, min_nrm_idx] = min(AA_nrm);
        x_hat = x_4nrm(:,min_nrm_idx);
        k_hat = find(x_hat);
        k = find(x);
        %% error calculation for ML detector
        cmp = isequal(k,k_hat);
        if cmp == 0
           error_ML = error_ML+1;
       else
           error_ML = error_ML+0;
        end
        err_cnt_ML = err_cnt_ML+error_ML;
    end
         toterr_cnt_ML = [ toterr_cnt_ML, err_cnt_ML];
        
        
end
ber_ML = toterr_cnt_ML./(iter); % simulated BER
%% Plot
SNRdB = 0:3:21;
figure(1)
semilogy(SNRdB,ber_ML,'g -','LineWidth',1);

grid on
xlabel('SNR in dB')
ylabel('BER')
```

Comment: It's pretty difficult to diagnose errors in complex, long pieces of code like this one; even more so if you don't even explain what is wrong with it. The possibilities range from a syntax error to a 0.1 dB discrepancy with theory. I'd suggest explaining exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @MBaz Thank u sir for your response...The problem I am facing is that I am trying to Plot  bit error rate (BER) Versus Signal to Noise ratio (SNR) plot, however it is not coming properly... I mean errors are not decreasing with increase in SNR....